# PHP devserver 17 not working

Tags: php

I have installed PHP devserver 17 and when I open a dashboard I get the message.

> MSVCR110.dll not found.

I have installed this DLL from the Microsoft website but it still does not work.

The DLL is there but Devserver cant find it!

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not use WAMP? It works perfectly

Comment: @Nick [Xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) is better, works on Linux/Windows/Mac

Comment: And did you restart your machine after installing the DLL?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is available on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/517704/56633).

> You need VS C++ 2012. Go here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679
>
> You need to download the x86 version if you install the 64bit version it will give the same error.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and sugestions I will try and find out what works.